# How do you create a Protobuf Struct from a Python Dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, struct, protocol-buffers

I get the following attribute error

> AttributeError: 'Struct' object has no attribute 'fields'

if I want to use the `update` method of [`google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types.Struct`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py)

Protobuf version is 3.71.

---

**MWE**:

```
from google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types import Struct

s = Struct()
s.update({"key": "value"})
```

---

The bigger context of this question is that I want to create a message  with a `google.protobuf.Struct` field in python for sending to pass to the generated RPC client.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok, I immediately found out how to do this after writing the question. Leaving the answer for anyone else who might end up having this problem.

We have to import `Struct` from `google.protobuf.struct_pb2`. Then `update` will work without a problem.

Hence,

```
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct

s = Struct()
s.update({"key": "value"})
```

will return an object with representation

```
fields {
  key: "key"
  value {
    string_value: "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the dict from the Struct?

Comment: @learn2day There's the [protobuf-to-dict](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf-to-dict/) package. I don't see a good reason why this would be necessary though. Structs in Python basically behave like Dicts anyway.

Comment: Thanks! They do, but they can't be jsonified, and that was a problem when trying to return from an api. Also found `{q: v for q, v in struct.items()}` works :)

Comment: @learn2day Yeah a dict comprehension works for the uppermost items. Keep in mind that this is only a shallow transformation though. ;) You will have to do this recursively for all nested Structs.

Comment: my protobuf object doesn't appear to have the update method. I get error: `AttributeError: update`

Comment: @JamesOwers are you importing `google.protobuf.struct_pb2.Struct`?

Comment: I'm importing thus: `from my_package.my_subpackage.my_module_pb2 import MyStruct`

Comment: Is this a class generated from a _.proto_ file?

Comment: Curious, any way to dump this as a `proto` file? I want to streamline building of the `.proto` files by just passing a dict to a function. the function should generate the `.proto`

Answer (score 5):

Should be as simple as

```
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct
from google.protobuf import json_format

s = Struct()
s.update({"key": "value"})

json_format.MessageToDict(s)
```