# Protobuf list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I'm trying to define a list of dictionaries in my .proto

All the examples I've found provide a dictionary with a single key, value pair:

```
message Pair {
   string key = 1;
   string value = 2;
}

message Dictionary {
   repeated Pair pairs = 1;
}
```

or something like:

```
message Dictionary {
    message Pair {
        map<string, string> values = 1;
    }
    repeated Pair pairs = 1;
}
```

but how would I handle a larger dictionary of mixed types?

```
{
'k1': 1,
'k2': 2,
'k3': 'three',
'k4': [1,2,3]
}
```

To further complicate things, once I've defined the dictionary of mixed values I need to create a message that is a list of these dictionaries. I assume that is as easy as creating a another repeated message with the dictionary nested:

```
message DictList {
    repeated Dictionary dlist = 1;
}
```

Comment: You can try `google.protobuf.Struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas I came up with:

1. It seems it should be possible (if you know all value types upfront) to use `oneof` for value (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof). That could solve the problem, e.g.

```
message Value {
    oneof oneof_values {
        string svalue = 1;
        int ivalue = 2;
        ...
    }
}

message Pair {
   string key = 1;
   Value value = 2;
}

message Dictionary {
   repeated Pair pairs = 1;
}
```

You can't use `map` or `repeated` inside of `oneof` though.

2. You could use optional fields and define them all as values in message definition. Then set only those, you actually use.
3. You could use wrappers, or known types, e.g. `Value`: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value

## EDIT

for the `Value`, it could be used like this:

```
map<string, google.protobuf.Value> dict = 1;
```

4. Use `struct` (as suggested by for_stack), could be seen here: [How do you create a Protobuf Struct from a Python Dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303736/how-do-you-create-a-protobuf-struct-from-a-python-dict)

Comment: can't define value twice in oneof

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. So in this context it's basically same as using optional fields. It's still usable, but ugly. :/ So it seems best would be to use struct as suggested by for_stack. This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303736/how-do-you-create-a-protobuf-struct-from-a-python-dict Updating answer.