# How can arbitrary values be used in the map field of protobuf and set in Python code?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

With protobuf, I want to send arbitrary fields to the server. Trying to set dict in Python with multiple values like int and string, I received the error: `expected google.protobuf.Value got int` and `must be instance of same class: expected google.protobuf.Any got int`.

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Request {
  string name = 1;
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any|Value> attrs = 2;
}

message Response {
  string resp = 1;
}

service Service1 {
  rpc Authenticate(Request) returns (Response);
}
```

Client:

```
attrs = {"int_value": 1, "string_value": "test"}
request = Request(name="test", attrs=attrs)
```

I tried to pack dict before sending it, but I was unable to pack it with `any().Pack()` due to the following error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'`

How can i send multiple values of any type?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the `google/protobuf/struct` type (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303736/how-do-you-create-a-protobuf-struct-from-a-python-dict) about how to use with dictionary

Comment: Does [this reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) answer your question?